# How to install chartjs on laravel 6 via npm

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, chart.js, laravel-charts

I would like to ask how install and integrate chartjs@2.9.4 with my laravel application.

I use cdn links right now but later it wont be an option for me later.

Used cdn links:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"</script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-chart-treemap@0.2.3"></script>
```

Method I tried:

1. Installing chartjs

```
npm i chart.js@2.9.4
```

2. Add this line in webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.copy('node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js', 'public/chart.js/chart.js');
```

3. Then run this from command line:

```
npm run dev
```

4. In the blade you want the chart on:

```
<script src="{{ asset('chart.js/chart.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the method you tried? Any errors? To answer this question correct, we have to know more about your environment. I think this highly depends on your frontend build process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the package:

```
npm install chart.js
```

Make a file called something like `/resources/js/mychart.js`:

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // ...
});
```

In your `/resources/js/app.js`, add the following, at the top:

```
import './mychart.js';
```

Now run your build, to compile your JavaScript into one file.

```
npm run dev
```

Laravel Mix, will already have a line for compiling the app.js file.

Now whenever you reference `/public/js/app.js`, your chart will be included there too.

```html
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

---

If you'd like a separate file, then change your `webpack.mix.js` file to this:

```js
mix.js('/resources/js/chart.js', 'public/js');
```

And remember to remove it from the imports in the `/resources/js/app.js` file.